# CSS: how to style on character height versus line height

Tags: css

Bear with me here, but assuming this code:

```
<style>
  span {
    color: black;
    background-color: black;
  }
</style>
<span>Hello world</span>
```

**Hello world**

Gives a result that looks like this:

███████████

Is it possible to apply style to just the *letter height*, versus the font/line height? In effect ending up with  something that looks like this:

█▄██▄ ▄▄▄██

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No (not with a background color anyway). Background colors apply to the entire element (e.g., span element), which is essentially a box as determined by the CSS box model. The [official recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/colors.html#background) from the W3C specifies that a background color will fill the content, padding, and border areas of the box model. The [CSS3 background (candidate recommendation)](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#background-clip) offers a bit more power for you to control where background colors apply, but not much.

If you really want the effect you've just demonstrated in your question, I think a JavaScript function to convert "short" characters (e.g., "w") to "▄" and "tall" characters (e.g., "h") to "█" would work nicely. [Here's a demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xySuQ/).

Comment: @yisela thanks :-) I should point out that the JavaScript I wrote will only work for the simple "hello world" example, but it could improved...

Comment: yep, it shouldn't be to hard to define two groups of characters (short and tall), and replace them accordingly. Nice.

Comment: Interesting idea. Since [it doesn't work well with non-monospaced font's](http://jsfiddle.net/xySuQ/5/) for keeping to the original character width, do you have a suggestion to overcome that? Also, it is a little unclear if the OP still want's the letter characters available for selection or not, and if so, this would need to be applied as an underlay to the original characters.

Comment: If only there were a font that displayed characters this way, then characters would still be available for selection (i.e., you could copy and paste into a text editor to discover what characters were "behind" those mysterious boxes). With regards to the monospace issue, you could do a more complex character mapping using other [box-like characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character). So, in short, my solution is really only good if you want the basic visual effect and nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a way using ONLY CSS, but you could use a function in PHP like imagefontheight: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefontheight.php and dynamically create your block elements from the specified font...

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of to get the effect purely by CSS requires:

1. An obscenely excessive amount of extra html markup.
2. A willingness to allow for some slight inexactness to the height of the background in comparison to the character itself.
3. A meticulous amount of testing on the particular font(s) you are going to use it on to see what results you are likely to get across browsers.

In other words: it really better be well worth the effort, and it probably ought to be used on only a very short string of text.

Here's [**an example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zPw4E/32/) with the word color left contrasting to see how the background fits the letters. **Note: this undoubtedly will have some variation on height and spacing above/below letters based on browser and font's being seen by you.** The use of a `:before` pseudo-element to achieve the effect means accommodations would need to be made for older browsers (IE7 and under).

Here's the basic code in the fiddle.

```
<span>H</span><span class="short">e</span><span>l</span><span>l</span><span class="short">o</span><span class="short">w</span> <span class="short">w</span><span class="short">o</span><span class="short">r</span><span>l</span><span>d</span>
```

```css
  span {
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    height: 1em;
  }

  span:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: .2em;
    right: 0;
    bottom: .1em;
    left: 0;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: -1;
  }

  span.short:before {
    top: .4em;
  }
```